# install pr2_description

Tags: urdf, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to view the PR2 URDF file, so I think I need to install the [pr2_description package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_description) in ROS.
How can I do this, this isn't covered in the tutorials as I can recall.

Thanks,
Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10508/install-pr2_description/) by [Peter](https://answers.ros.org/users/790/peter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently there is also a guide explaining this on this website: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/StackInstallation

---

Originally posted by [Peter](https://answers.ros.org/users/790/peter/) with karma: 36 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think
`sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-pr2-common`
contains that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3